# Distinct by using criteria api on java

Tags: java, hibernate-criteria

This is my classes, **Dossiers**, **Candidats**, **Formations** and **Actions :**

```js
public class Dossiers implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer iddossier;
    private Candidat candidat;
    private Formation formation;
    private String currentstate;

}

public class Candidats implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer idcandidat;
    private String name;

}


public class Formation implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer idFormation;
    private String formationName;

}


public class Actions implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer idAction;
    private Date dateexecution;
    private List<Dossiers> listDossiers;
}
```

And this is my code and want to get a list with distinct IDs.

```
DetachedCriteria  criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Dossier.class);

if(thisview > 0){

    criteria.createAlias("formation", "formation").add(Restrictions.eq("formation.idformation", thisview));
}

if (state != null) {

    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("currentstate", state));
}
if (name != null){

    criteria.createAlias("person", "person").add(Restrictions.eq("candidat.name", name));
}

criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("iddossier"));
List<Dossier> dList =  findByCriteria(criteria);
return dList;
```

but when I add this line bellow, I got an error

criteria.setProjection(Projections.alias(Projections.groupProperty("iddossier"), "iddossiers"));

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` aggregates all entries with the same value for the given column. Therefore the result is not a list of entries that are modeled by your entity class but something different.

If you have a table like

```
ID | NAME        | CITY
1  | Alice       | London
2  | Bob         | Berlin
3  | Charlie     | London
```

and `GROUP BY city`, you would get `[Berlin, London]`. Hibernate could not return an entity for a specific person because there are two people living in London.

That's why queries with a projection return other types (depending on the projection used).

Comment: thx @Simon Bungartz, I want something like that, only two row as your table : 1 | Alice | London AND 2 | Bob | Berlin

Comment: If each value can only occur once, then why do you want to use group by?

Comment: my result without group by and by joining is : **idDossier** : 100 | **Name** : thisName | **Date** : 2013-01-01 the 2nd record is **idDossier** : 200 | **Name** : anOtherName | **Date** : 2013-02-01 the last one is : **idDossier** : 100 | **Name** : thisName | **Date** : 2014-02-01. by grouping by idDossier, I want to get only the 1st and the 2nd record.

Comment: This is not exactly what GROUP BY is for. Usually it is for aggregating values (sum, average, min, max, etc). To do what you want you need to be more specific about which record you want to select if there are multiple with the same ID. Then we can figure out how to do this with Hibernate.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but by creating my query by using GROUP BY in mysql, I got the result what I want, I want to group all records by the same ID as I wrote in comment, something like distinct ...

Comment: Can you post that query?

Comment: **this is my sql query :**
 SELECT  dossier.iddossier, 
   candidat.name,
   dossier.state,
   actions.dateexecution 

 FROM candidat,
   dossier,
   actions


 WHERE  dossier.idcandidat = candidat.idcandidat
  AND actions.iddossier = dossier.iddossier
 group by dossier.iddossier

Comment: This statement will not work on most databases. They enforce that all values that are selected are either in the `GROUP BY` clause or aggregations. This is the case for the exact reason I explained above. It is not defined whether it should return _2013-01-01_ or _2014-02-01_ for **Date** where **idDossier** is 100. And I don't know what you expect there (since dateexecution isn't even part of `Dossier`). Please update your question with the definition of `Dossier` and maybe also the other entities that are involved.

Comment: Why do you want to use the group by? What is the problem when you use the Criteria you posted without the group by?